# How to "feed" data from view to model?

Tags: apache-flex, model-view-controller

I know I might not be supposed to be doing this, but I see no way around this.

I have a bunch of tabs (TabNavigator) each containing a datagrid based on the same view but with different content.

In the model, I have an Id specifying which tab I am in (and based on that I will subsequently fill the grids from within my controller).

My problem is, how to feed the Id.

What I tried to do so far is, in my View:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.to.my.controller.MyController;
        import com.to.my.models.MyModel;

        import mx.events.ListEvent;

        [Inject][Bindable] public var controller:MyController;
        [Inject][Bindable] public var model:MyModel;

        this.model.tabTypeId = this.parentDocument.myTabNavigator.selectedChild.id;


    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

But apparently this is wrong at compile time:

```
The this keyword can not be used in static methods. It can only be used in instance methods, function closures, and global code.
```

Total flex newbie... sorry...

Thanks

Comment: Your logic is in static scope. Take a look at this answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922591/1120-access-of-undefined-property/11923177#11923177

Comment: Why did you label this MVC? Referring to the parentDocument like that is about the furthest from MVC that you can get. You should populate the tabTypeID on the model at a higher level (likely whatever component is injecting it into your View).